# RPI2b - "ALSA: Underrun Occurred"

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, alsa, pyaudio

I am running a python script on a rpi2b + a cirrus logic audio card. I want to iir filter music. I open a stream with pyaudio and have my callback function.

The first (around) 5 seconds it runs fine and then I get this error... Couldnt find anything helpful with google, completely frustrated ^^

What kind of information can I provide you? Where do I turn on debug options and can show you some outputs?

Comment: "Underrun" means that your code did not write new samples to the device in time.

Comment: And how can I fix this? Python too slow? :/ Since the very first seconds it runs good. When measuring the magnitude response it works and filters but after a certain moment it produces this error. If setting up everything on a pc I dont get this error (okay obviously more power but is that it?)

Comment: As a test, remove the actual computation and output a bunch of zero samples (or a sine wave) instead; this should be faster.

Comment: with the rpi3b I dont have this problem... just throw the 2b away ^^

Answer (score 0):

ALSA Underrun means , you are not giving data to ALSA in proper intervals. ie, your algorithm is not enough fast in rpi2b. So you need to improve your algorithm or you need a faster chip.